# Seeking ca 1801 records of 1st Helston Volunteers?

Tags: england, military-records, cornwall, 1800s-decade

My 4th great grandfather Joseph Billin(g) lived from 1776 to 1839 and was a Tailor, Mercer & Draper at Helston, Cornwall, England, where he was baptised, married and buried.

Today I found in Ancestry.com's "Cornwall, England, Militia and Sea Fencibles Index, 1780 - 1831" that he also served in the military:

```
Name    Joseph (x) Billin
Birth Place Helston area
Military Year   1801
Military Place  Cornwall, England
Unit or Occupation  1st Helston Volunteers
```

The record comes from "Cornwall Record Office; Truro, Cornwall, England; Cornwall Militia; Class Number: AD/1865/22".

I have not been able to find any mention of the "1st Helston Volunteers" anywhere else so far but would the record above most likely come from [the set below](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/details/r/C7242973)?

```
Reference:  WO 13/4235
Description:    
Cornwall Helston
Date:   1799 - 1802
Held by:    The National Archives, Kew
Legal status:   Public Record(s)
Closure status: Open Document, Open Description
Context of this record 
All departments
WO - Records created or inherited by the War Office, Armed Forces, Judge Advocate General, and related bodies
Records of other administrative departments of the War Office
WO 13 - War Office and predecessors: Militia and Volunteers Muster Books and Pay Lists
VOLUNTEERS 1797 - 1814
WO 13/4235 - Volunteers
WO 13/4235 - Cornwall Helston
```

Has anyone come across any records of the 1st Helston Volunteers around 1801 that I could examine to try and learn more about Joseph Billin's service in it?

Comment: Just a little background about Volunteers Corps - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Volunteer_Corps